# How to install WhatsApp on an iPad 4 without 3G?

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

I own an iPad 4 without 3G (functioning only Wi-Fi) running iOS 7. How can I install [WhatsApp](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997) on this iPad?

Answer (score 1):

From the [FAQ on whatsapp.com](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/20951556):

> Other devices are not supported at this time. If you try to download WhatsApp on an unsupported device, you will receive a message that your device is not supported and you will not be able to download WhatsApp. **We currently do not support tablets, computers, or Wi-Fi only devices**, and do not plan to do so in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 1):

I've run Whatsapp on a [jailbroken iPad](http://www.redmondpie.com/whatsapp-for-ipad-ipad-2-whatspad-download-how-to-install/). But apparently it is also possible on a non-jailbroken iPad.

You will need a mobile phone to receive the first authentication text-message and the free application iFunBox to put the IPA file on the iPad.
Instructions can be found at [Redmond Pie](http://www.redmondpie.com/install-whatsapp-on-ipad-and-ipod-touch-without-jailbreak-video/).